# CSS float left not working right

Tags: css, css-float

i'm trying to split two divs into two section, left and right. With the left one being static (300px height) and right one is not static (such as posts and comments). With a footer at the bottom.

```
<div>
    <div>
    <div class="right"><img src="images/members/bigava/crays.png" style="width: 630px; height: 130px;" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="left" style="float: left;"><img src="images/members/ava/crays.jpg" style="width:120px; height:80px;" /></div>
    </div>
```

I made my main div with a width of 760px, hence with those setting, i still have 10px to spare. The problem now is, i cannot assign float-right to the div with right class, and can only assign float-left to the div with left class. I tried changing the div up and down, reassigning the positions, but what i get isn't what i want. Any help?

edit

```
CSS
.right {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 12px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.left {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 10px;
color: #000000;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

This is the results i get which i don't want
[image]

[image]

what i want is
[image]

Comment: Please provide a clearer idea of how it is "not working right". Screenshots, for example.

Comment: why are you wrapping "left" and "right" divs into other placeholder div's. Do those have any purpose.

Comment: i'm new to coding sorry, i define left and right class as just a class for the div, but only assign the style="float: left;" in the <div class="left">

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`DIV` is  a block element  so you can give `float` or `inline-block` to your `right div` to take its actual `width` like this:

```
.right{float:right}
```

EDIT:

answer your comment below

if you give `float` to the `divs` then you have to `clear its parent` like this :

```
<div style="overflow:hidden"> 
    <div class="right" style="float: right;"><img src="images/members/bigava/crays.png" style="width: 630px; height: 130px;" /></div> 
    <div class="left" style="float: left;"><img src="images/members/ava/crays.jpg" style="width:120px; height:80px;" /></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to get rid of some divs or assign floating to parent divs of right, left divs.

```
<div> 
    <div class="right" style="float: right;"><img src="images/members/bigava/crays.png" style="width: 630px; height: 130px;" /></div> 
    <div class="left" style="float: left;"><img src="images/members/ava/crays.jpg" style="width:120px; height:80px;" /></div> 
    <div class="footer" style="clear: both;"><img src="images/members/ava/crays.jpg" style="width:760px; height:80px;" /></div> 
</div>
```

this should work.

Comment: but by assigning float: right, wouldn't that make it overlap the footer below?

Comment: i updated my comment including a footer div. they don't overlap if you use "clear: both"

Answer (score 2):

If you do the width measurements right, you can get that layout by actually floating everything to the left. Your div order has to stack right, and it will naturally float to where you want it. You have more divs than necessary. Be sure to clean this up.